# How to abbreviate home directory in emacs C-x C-f

Tags: file, emacs

When I type C-x C-f in emacs, it shows the full path to the file, which happens to be very big:

```
/mnt/dutiaw4/aw/fmario/work/file.txt
```

I would like it to abbreviate the home directory, something like:

```
~/work/file.txt
```

How can I do that?

Comment: There are different mechanisms depending where this name is being shown.  Is in the minibuffer, or in a directory listing, or...

Comment: @Andew Swann: in the minibuffer actually, when I hit C-x C-f to open a file.

Comment: Is your `HOME` environment variable set to the `/mnt/dutiaw4/aw/fmario` directory?

Comment: What @SteveVinoski said. Just set your `HOME`. Then you can use `~/...`.

Comment: I tried already to set my HOME to all kinds of prefixes emacs is showing on the minibuffer (including /mnt/dutiaw4/aw/fmario) but it still shows the prefixes instead of ~ when I hit C-x C-f.

edit: ok, I figured it out, the HOME was not what it should be when the terminal was starting. No clue why this happened, the admin just messed everything up here. Thanks a lot!